# Iterator remove

Tags: java

Im removing some fields from an XML String based on the list of fieldsToRemove.

```
   List<String> fieldsToRemove = //list of fields to be remove.
    
    String eventString = //XML String.
    
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(eventString.split("\n")));
    Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    
     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String line = iterator.next();
                for (String field : fieldsToRemove) {
                    if (line.contains(field)) {
                        iterator.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
```

But im receiving this error, wherenever the XML String is oneliner (unformatted):

```
20211015;07:16:01: java.lang.IllegalStateException
20211015;07:16:01:      at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:874)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code causing you problems? And you are not calling remove again?

remove() throws IllegalStateException - if the next method has not yet been called, or the remove method has already been called after the last call to the next method

Comment: It looks like you're calling `itr.remove()` too often. If `line.contains(field)` is `true` more than once per `line`, this is very likely to happen. Consider adding `break` to the `if` statement of the inner `for` loop right after `iterator.remove()`.

Comment: @majusebetter you are right.. Since its one liner, it might tend to call itr.remove() more than once, if fields containts is Still true on certain fields... Let me try to put the break..

Comment: @majusebetter its seems working..

Comment: That's great! :)

Comment: @majusebetter – Would you please promote your comment to an answer? Otherwise only the wrong answer remains …

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look what is really happening here.

Suppose you have the following text:

```
<root><child></child></root>
```

Splitting by `\n` (which is not present in the string) will cause your list to have a single element.

And `fieldsToRemove` looks like this:

```java
List<String> fieldsToRemove = List.of("root", "child");
```

Then the following happens:

- `String line = iterator.next();` – You retrieve the only line from the iterator, which contains both "root" and "child";
- `for (String field : fieldsToRemove) {` – You iterate over *all* elements-to-remove...
- ...and `if (line.contains(field)) {` if it is present in the line...
- ...`iterator.remove();` it.

So "root" is found, the line is removed, **and then "child" is found, which causes the *same* line to be removed *again***. Of course, the `iterator` doesn't like this, and throws an exception.

In order to 'fix' this, add a `break` below the call to `remove()`:

```java
iterator.remove();
break;
```

---

However, I'm not really sure why you would remove *the whole line* within an XML document. Why don't you grab an XML parser?